# Why bitcoin does not generate and support Segwit addresses by default automatically?

Tags: segregated-witness, bitcoin-core-development, address-generation

I downloaded the latest bitcoin core, but the generated wallet and address was not a segwit. Why bitcoin core, does not support segwit by default? and when it will be changed?

Comment: The address is a segwit script (P2SH-P2WPKH), but it was not a bech32 address, if that's what you mean.